# MongoDB: Get latest 10 items in different data model?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, mongoengine

I'm trying to do a personal blog system with MongoDB. The blog system designed to support both formal article and short tweets, which have similar but different data structures. For example, an article must have a title, but tweets must not; both them have a creation date.

There is also a timeline feature in design. The timeline will show latest 10 items, no matter the item is an article or a tweet, and when "load more" button pressed, there will show the 10-20 items...

So I think there are two method to design the database schema

1. Save articles and tweets into separate collections.
2. Save all things into a single collection, add a "type" field for specifying.

And I have three questions:

1. If I use method 1, how to implement the "latest 10 items" query?  Any literal explanation, or example code in MongoDB query language, mongoose, mongoengine or else, is welcome.
2. If I use traditional SQL DB (like MySQL), is there a common method to solve the "latest 10 items" problem ?
3. Which methods fits the MongoDB's philosophy more ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1 : If you are saving *articles* and *tweets* into separate collections, you'll either have to do application-side joining or use `$lookup` operator, which will not work if you have sharded collections. I tend to avoid operators that have that limitation.

Question 2 : I don't work with SQL, can't help you there.

Question 3 : Saving everything into a single collection will definitely fit MongoDB philosophy more. MongoDB should be fast at retrieving, although slower in inserts and updates. Doing either application-side joining or having to use `$lookup` kind of throw its ability to embed documents out of the windows.

As for your data model, here's my take. I used java driver and I used to have a custom deserializer/serializer to handle the document to POJO mapping. I believe it's natively supported in Mongo Java Driver 3.5, not sure if it's there for Mongoose already. In any case, you may define a Model/Object that contains all fields in both models, it'll then serialize accordingly, regardless which type you're fetching from DB using method 2. The model will get a little messy as you add more fields though, so some clever naming might be necessary